# Help to solve inequation: $\frac{2x-3}{x+1} \leq 1$

Tags: inequality

I`m reviewing some inequality content but I can't wrap my head around it.

I`m currently solving this inequation: $\frac{2x-3}{x+1} \leq 1$

The final answer is: (-1, 4]

I would like to know to solve this, and why the solving process below is wrong since it`s answer is $(-\infty, 4]$.

$\frac{2x-3}{x+1} \leq 1$

$2x-3 \leq x+1$

$x-4 \leq 0$

$x \leq 4$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that when you multiply both sides of an inequality by a quantity, you must reverse the direction of the inequality if that quantity is negative

Comment: you could consider the case where $x+1$ is less than $0$, but then you have to reverse the inequality when you multiply both sides by $x+1$, so you get $2x-3\color{red}\ge x+1$, and see where that takes you

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is that$$\frac{2x-3}{x+1}\leqslant1\iff2x-3\leqslant x+1$$only holds in $(-1,\infty)$. In $(-\infty,-1)$, you have$$\frac{2x-3}{x+1}\leqslant1\iff2x-3\geqslant x+1$$because then $x+1<0$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to restrict the division and unite both results.